# Finding the first open position in a NxN forced matrix

Tags: sql-server, database, matrix

I am building a system for a client that employs a 3x3 forced matrix. Among the many challenges I have encountered along the way, one has stood out the most and I have yet to solve it. My task is to get the first available (empty) position under a given point (it must move from left to right and downward). My best attempt at this was to get the entire downline of a given point, then, cycle through each of them until I found one with < 3 child nodes. The problem with this attempt is that the first query does not give the downline in order from left to right and top to bottom.

Please feel free to share any insight on this, all answers and comments are welcome. Forgive me if I made this far more confusing than it needed to be.

Comment: What fields do you have in the record? Do you have like "child1", "child2" and "child3". Also, to be clear, when you say a 3x3 matrix, do you mean that the most people one person can have in their downline is (3 + 9 + 27)=39? Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: If you added some sample data, and the desired sample output, it would be easier to understand your requirements.

Comment: Each member in the matrix has a member_id, parent_id, status and rank. Each member has a maximum of 3 direct childs. I tried to add a couple pictures but I have not reached a proper rep.